# how to get balance sheet (debit , credit , balance) from transactions table in SQL?

Tags: sql

if I have transactions table like that:

```
+----+--------+------------+-------------+--------+
| id | userID | debitAccID | creditAccID | amount |
+----+--------+------------+-------------+--------+
|  1 |      1 |          1 |           2 |    500 |
|  2 |      1 |          1 |           3 |    600 |
|  3 |      1 |          3 |           1 |    200 |
+----+--------+------------+-------------+--------+
```

how what query to use to get a table for account with id 1 like that:

```
+----+--------+------------+-------------+--------+
|   debit      | credit      |balance |
+----+--------+------------+-------------+--------+
| |        500 |             |    500 |
| |        600 |             |   1100 |
| |            |          200|    900 |
+----+--------+------------+-------------+--------+
                                  900
```

Answer (score 2):

Assuming the `id` column shows the correct order of transactions, you can use `case` and `window` with the default of `rows between unlimited preceding and current row` to get your output:

```
select id, user_id, 
       case when user_id = debit_acc_id then amount else 0 end as debit,
       case when user_id = credit_acc_id then amount else 0 end as credit,
       sum(case when user_id = debit_acc_id then amount else 0 end) over w 
       - sum(case when user_id = credit_acc_id then amount else 0 end) over w as balance
  from transactions
 where user_id = 1
window w as (partition by user_id order by id)
 order by user_id, id;
```

*db<>fiddle [here](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_14&fiddle=a36488ed3cbec58715923cd44a253f2a)*